# .showSaveDialog() does not execute when used with a button in a form

Tags: javascript, html, electron

Using a `<form>` tag in my case was not entirely necessary, but I would like to know why my button

```
    <button onclick="saveFile()">Save</button>
```

does nothing when it has been placed within two form tags. The `saveFile()` function is a basic `.showSaveDialog()` with fs to write the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A button inside a form by default submits the form. Unless the `type` attribute has been set to `button`.

```
<button onclick="saveFile()" type='button'>Save</button>
```

I think in your case it's submitting the form and reloading the page, that's why you're not able to see `saveFile()` in actions.